# Словосочетание прилагательного и существительного в родительном падеже

Tags: грамматика

Помогите найти примеры словосочетаний прилагательного и зависимого от него существительного, стоящего в родительном падеже (без предлога). Как "ждущий рассвета", только здесь главное слово "ждущий" - не прилагательное, а причастие. Не подходят словосочетания типа "рядовой гвардии", потому что здесь "рядовой", хотя по форме и прилагательное, но фактически выполняет роль существительного (так что всё словосочетание не может быть согласуемым определением). Особенно интересны такие словосочетания, где прилагательное можно поставить в краткую форму.

Answer (score 1):

Сам придумал: полный (полон) воды.